# how to install gcc

Tags: software-installation, gcc

Issue with install, searched gnu.org - unfortunately manual is more than 810 pages thick without instruct for install;

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc.pdf

Plus manual pages in ubuntu is 8529+ lines (again) without straight forward instruct as to install..

Noting that to configure GCC, it must be made from a shell environment first;

```
 % mkdir objdir
 % cd objdir
 % srcdir/configure [options] [target]
```

Not sure whether this is the same with distributions through package manager on ubuntu, version 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 (or) just releases through gnu.org - versions 5.3 (the latest).

Comment: Ubuntu includes gcc by default.  Why do you need to install it?

Comment: @ZeissIkon he probably wants a newer compiler version.

Comment: I've always had to install it in lubuntu.  However, it's just a simple `sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: `apt install gcc`?

Answer (score 0):

If you install an updated version of gcc through a package manager such as synaptic, or by downloading and installing a .deb file, you won't need to `make` gcc.  You'd only need to do that if you're compiling it from source, which isn't necessary for ordinary use.

In fact, unless you removed the gcc package (which would break most of your Ubuntu installation), there's unlikely to be any need to update gcc beyond using the version that comes preinstalled in Ubuntu.